# Is the anime of "Tokyo Ghoul:re" (season 3) canon?

Tags: tokyo-ghoul

Can anyone confirm or deny if *Tokyo Ghoul:re*, the 3rd season of the anime is canon or not? It seems like a major step after the events of the first and second seasons so I'm pretty darn bewildered by all the new characters

Comment: Related: [Before watching “Tokyo Ghoul:re” anime, is it necessary to read the manga to understand the story?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/46374/2516) and [Is watching the first 2 seasons of the anime enough to understand “Tokyo Ghoul:re” manga without reading prior manga?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/33813/2516)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes, *Tokyo Ghoul:re* is canon**

If you take a look in the [wiki](http://tokyoghoul.wikia.com/wiki/Tokyo_Ghoul_(manga)) you can see that Tokyo Ghoul:re (東京喰種トーキョーグール:re, Tōkyō Gūru:re) is a sequel to the Japanese manga series Tokyo Ghoul written and illustrated by Sui Ishida.

And yes, *Tokyo Ghoul:re* picked up 2 years after the events that ended *Tokyo Ghoul*

Answer (score 1):

Just like the original anime Tokyo Ghoul:re is skipping a lot of exposition. They never explained how Ken Kaneki lost his memory. They will explain everything through flashbacks.