# How did Kaneki discover Touka was a ghoul?

Tags: tokyo-ghoul

I've previously watched the anime and have just now started the manga (I know I'm terribly late) My mind is blown away by how different the manga is from the anime. (I'm even questioning if I'm reading the right thing due to the detail and differences) I feel like the question presented as my title will help resolve some of my suspicions. Did Studio Pierrot really cut so much detail out as well as change some parts of the story/events? Have I really been missing out on so much?

If someone could explain I'd deeply appreciate it

Thanks!

Comment: There are 2 different questions: the title and the question body. The question body seems to have been answered in [Why did Tokyo Ghoul √A completely deviate from the manga?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/18391/2516).

Comment: The question in your title is already answered in the anime and manga. It was shown in the earlier episodes/chapters. I suggest rereading/rewatching in case you missed it. Your other question, as mentioned, is already answered in the aforementioned link. In addition, yes, the manga deviated much from the anime and you're missing some important details/events not in the anime. I suggest reading the manga in its entirety.

Answer (score -1):

I've only watched the anime, but Kaneki discovered that Touka was a ghoul when he had just become a ghoul and entered Nishiki's territory. Touka had saved Kaneki from him.

Comment: It might be helpful to mention which episode this happens in, so OP can go back and re-watch it.